# I'm getting a undefined method error in Ruby on Rails and I'm not sure why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cloud9

Basically I have 2 tables called Employees and Sales. I have a form where you input the Employee name and it should show you what phones they have sold. Every time I input the name I get this error

```
undefined method `sales' for #<Employee:0x007f013e23fdc0>
```

And it highlights the @sale_list = r.sales part of the code shown below (my controller)

```
class ShowEmployeeSalesController < ApplicationController
  def employeesaleout
    @employee_name = params[:employee_name_in]
    r = Employee.find_by_name_id(@employee_name)
    @sale_list = r.sales
  end
end
```

This is my code for the input view:

```
<h2>
  Please enter the name of the Employee for whom you want to see the sales 
</h2>

<%= form_tag(show_employee_sales_employeesaleout_path, :controller =>  "ShowEmployeeSales", :action => "employeesaleout", :method => "post") do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :Employee_Name %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :employee_name_in %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Submit Employee Name" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my code for output view:

```
<h1>ShowEmployeeSales#employeesaleout</h1>
    <center>
      <h1>
        These are the Sales for <%= @employee_name %> 
      </h1>
    </center><br /> <br />

    <center>
      <table width = 65% border = 1> 
        <tr>
          <th> Phone Name </th>
          <th> Phone ID </th>
        </tr>   
        <% @sale_list.each do |m| %>     
          <tr> 
            <td> 
              <%= m.Mobile %> 
            </td> 
            <td> 
              <%= m.Employee %> 
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end %> 
      </table> 
    </center><br /> <br />
```

All of my tables have data in them.

Comment: Post your Employee model

Comment: Agreed. You need to post your Employee Model. If I had to guess, I'm assuming you don't have a `has_many :sales` defined on Employee.

Comment: I added the 'has_many :sales' part and it worked. However I have another problem now. Please see my comment below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your `Employee` model you should have:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales
end
```

and In your `Sale` model:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :employee
end
```

Also you should have a column attribute `employee_id` in your `sales` table

```
t.integer :employee_id
```

happy coding :)

Comment: Okay so I added 'has_many :sales' and it worked! Now the only problem I have is that it doesn't show my the Mobile name that the employee sold and it doesn't show me the Employee id_no in the table. Instead it says "#<Mobile:0x0000000399b1c0>" for mobile and "#<Employee:0x00000003adbdf0>" for employee. How do I make it so that it shows me the Mobile name and the Employee id_no

Comment: Also I already have the 't.integer :employee_id'  in my Sales table.

Comment: update your question an past the employees and sales table. You can find it in your `db/schema.rb` file